# Beckhoff TcSysManager : No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, twincat

I'm trying to use the C# integration for the Beckhoff's Automation Interface. I've downloaded an example from Beckhoff's website to learn more about it. However, when I run it, I get an error saying that the constructor of the sysManager object isn't parameterless. This can't be true as there are several instances in Beckhoff's website instantiating this object with a parameterless constructor. Anyone has seen this before? Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using TCatSysManagerLib;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace LinkPLCProjectTC2
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string _tpyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\Templates\\Sample.tpy";
        private static TcSysManager _sysManager;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                _sysManager = new TcSysManager();
                _sysManager.NewConfiguration();

                ITcSmTreeItem plcNode = _sysManager.LookupTreeItem("TIPC");
                ITcSmTreeItem plc = plcNode.CreateChild(_tpyPath, 0, "", null);
                ITcSmTreeItem plcProject = _sysManager.LookupTreeItem("TIPC^Sample");

                _sysManager.SaveConfiguration(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + "\\Templates\\Sample.tsm");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error msg:

System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at LinkPLCProjectTC2.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\user\Desktop\LinkPLCProjectTC2_CSharp\LinkPLCProjectTC2\Program.cs:line 21
Press any key to continue . . .

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that Beckhoff's online documentation isn't updated. The following will work but you've got to make sure that the Twincat project that you are referencing is opened when you run this console app.

Also, make sure you import the helper class to your C# app so you can attach you Twincat solution to the DTE.

Finally, don't forget to add the references to your project. You'll need: envdte, envdte80, envdte90, envdte90a, envdte100 and TwincatSysManagerLib.

Tip, if you are trying save a component from your IO tree remember that not all children can be exported. For example, a load cell (Ep3356-0022) has the export method and consequently will work with the ExportChild() method from Automation Interface API. However the a stepper drive doesn't count with that, so you've got to use ProduceXML() instead.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TCatSysManagerLib;
using EnvDTE;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
class Program
{
    public static ITcSysManager11 sysMan;
    public static EnvDTE.DTE dte;
    public static EnvDTE.Project pro;
    public static EnvDTE.Solution sol;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dte = attachToExistingDte(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\TwinCAT_CNC\CNC_MACHINE.sln", "TcXaeShell.DTE.15.0");

        /* Attach system manager to the DTE solution's project object. */
        sol = dte.Solution;
        pro = sol.Projects.Item(1);
        sysMan = (ITcSysManager11)pro.Object;

        Console.WriteLine("Is TwinCat in Online Mode? " + sysMan.IsTwinCATStarted()); 
        Console.WriteLine("What's my target NetID? " + sysMan.GetTargetNetId()); 

        ITcSmTreeItem plc = sysMan.LookupTreeItem("TIID^Device 3 (EtherCAT)^Term 1 (EK1100)^Term 2 (EL7031)");
        //plc.ExportChild("Untitled1", @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Untitled1.tfzip");
        Console.WriteLine(plc.ProduceXml());
    }

    public static EnvDTE.DTE attachToExistingDte(string solutionPath, string progId)
    {
        EnvDTE.DTE dte = null;
        try
        {
            Hashtable dteInstances = AI_Example.Helper.GetIDEInstances(false, progId);
            IDictionaryEnumerator hashtableEnumerator = dteInstances.GetEnumerator();

            while (hashtableEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                EnvDTE.DTE dteTemp = (EnvDTE.DTE)hashtableEnumerator.Value;
                if (dteTemp.Solution.FullName == solutionPath)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found solution in list of all open DTE objects. " + dteTemp.Name);
                    dte = dteTemp;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        return dte;
    }
}
}
```

Helper class: Import it to your project, note the namespace

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 namespace AI_Example
 {
public class Helper
{
    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetRunningObjectTable(int reserved, out UCOMIRunningObjectTable prot);

    [DllImport("ole32.dll")]
    public static extern int CreateBindCtx(int reserved, out UCOMIBindCtx ppbc);

    public static string getFreeTcDirectory(string basePath)
    {
        int max = 1;
        List<string> directories = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(basePath));
        foreach (var directory in directories)
        {
            string[] dirNames = directory.Split('\\');
            if (dirNames[dirNames.Length - 1].Contains("TwinCAT Project"))
            {
                string number = dirNames[dirNames.Length - 1].Substring(15, dirNames[dirNames.Length - 1].Length - 15);
                if (Convert.ToInt32(number) > max)
                    max = Convert.ToInt32(number);
            }
        }
        max++;

        return "TwinCAT Project" + max.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a snapshot of the running object table (ROT).
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A hashtable mapping the name of the object
    //     in the ROT to the corresponding object</returns>
    public static Hashtable GetRunningObjectTable()
    {
        Hashtable result = new Hashtable();

        int numFetched;
        UCOMIRunningObjectTable runningObjectTable;
        UCOMIEnumMoniker monikerEnumerator;
        UCOMIMoniker[] monikers = new UCOMIMoniker[1];

        GetRunningObjectTable(0, out runningObjectTable);
        runningObjectTable.EnumRunning(out monikerEnumerator);
        monikerEnumerator.Reset();

        while (monikerEnumerator.Next(1, monikers, out numFetched) == 0)
        {
            UCOMIBindCtx ctx;
            CreateBindCtx(0, out ctx);

            string runningObjectName;
            monikers[0].GetDisplayName(ctx, null, out runningObjectName);

            object runningObjectVal;
            runningObjectTable.GetObject(monikers[0], out runningObjectVal);

            result[runningObjectName] = runningObjectVal;
        }

        return result;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Get a table of the currently running instances of the Visual Studio .NET IDE.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="openSolutionsOnly">Only return instances
    ///                   that have opened a solution</param>
    /// <returns>A hashtable mapping the name of the IDE
    ///       in the running object table to the corresponding
    ///                                  DTE object</returns>
    public static Hashtable GetIDEInstances(bool openSolutionsOnly, string progId)
    {
        Hashtable runningIDEInstances = new Hashtable();
        Hashtable runningObjects = GetRunningObjectTable();

        IDictionaryEnumerator rotEnumerator = runningObjects.GetEnumerator();
        while (rotEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string candidateName = (string)rotEnumerator.Key;
            if (!candidateName.StartsWith("!" + progId))
                continue;

            EnvDTE.DTE ide = rotEnumerator.Value as EnvDTE.DTE;
            if (ide == null)
                continue;

            if (openSolutionsOnly)
            {
                try
                {
                    string solutionFile = ide.Solution.FullName;
                    if (solutionFile != String.Empty)
                    {
                        runningIDEInstances[candidateName] = ide;
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
            else
            {
                runningIDEInstances[candidateName] = ide;
            }
        }
        return runningIDEInstances;
    }
}
}
```